# My React Native application is taking up ludicrous amount of space on my device

Tags: react-native

My React Native app I've written for benchmarking purposes in my Bachelors thesis is taking up crazy amount of space on my device (iPhone).
70,5MB to be precise. Since application size is a metric I am comparing in my research one could only wonder if this could be true..

Am I doing something wrong? (I am a beginner with React Native)

I will provide my entire code for the benchmark example where I've implemented recursive fibonacci (for benchmarking)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';


export default function App(){
const [n,setN] = useState(0);
const [Output,setOutput] = useState(0);

return(
<View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}>
      <Text>Enter a number for N: {Output}</Text>
      <TextInput
      style ={styles.input}
      placeholder ='Test'
      onChangeText={(val) => setN(val)}/>
      <Button style={styles.knapp} title ="Start" onPress={() => start()} ></Button>
    </View>

);


function start(){
  setOutput(fibonacci(n));
}

function fibonacci(n){
  if(n <= 2)
  return 1;
  else
  return fibonacci(n-2) + fibonacci(n -1);
}

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

input:{
borderWidth: 1,
marginTop: 30,
marginBottom: 30,
width: 100,
height:20,
color: '#777',
borderColor: '#777'
}, 
})
```

The Native Swift application in comparison only takes up around 465KB.

Are React Native apps usually this heavy?

I can also mention that the project was generated through

`react-native init projectname`

and I started coding from there.

Comment: It shouldn't be that heavy. Simple react native apps are around 7-8 MB, and yours should be around that. Check your folders for heavy assets.

Comment: @MIPB note what he said...  "The Native Swift application in comparison only takes up around 465KB."

Comment: I see, but I assumed he meant he developed two different apps (one with swift and one with react native). Something might have slipped into the folders. Anyways I had a similar problem and it was because of heavy filed automatically generated by react which could be deleted.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I have developed two different applications. One with Swift through Xcode. And the other application using React-Native. The Swift app takes up 465KB and the Cross-platform app takes up 70,5MB

Comment: @StefanSmudja open your ios folder of the RN project in XCode and analyze the files. See which of them are taking up that much space.

Comment: The only thing that I noticed in the ios folder is that the folder "Pods" is taking up 204MB, all these pods in the directory were generated when creating the project.